# Open File On Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library

I'm writing a vsix.  I'm trying to open a File on a class library marked as portable.  Due to platform specific issues you cannot directly pass a file location.

I have a file location and I Want to open a stream I don't care if it crash on other platforms it just needs to work on windows.

```
var closestResxPath= @"C:/Resources.Resx";

//How Can I open a text stream?    
var stream = null;    

using (var resxWriter = new ResourceWriter(stream))
{

}
```

**Note**

All of the TextReaders, StreamReaders only open with a stream an do not take a path

Comment: I've found that there are still many, many platform-specific tasks when writing anything targeting multiple platforms, and it's best to bite the bullet and design it with platform-specific assemblies from the very beginning. Adding it as an afterthought has always been a huge pain. Opening the file (and passing its stream to your portable stream-processing code) seems like a job for a class in one of the non-portable assemblies.

Comment: @HiredMind I'm creating a Roslyn Extension for VSIX, Everyone here works on windows desktop.   As you said I should put this in a platform specific Assembly, how can I add a platform specific assembly to a portable DLL

Comment: You got me there. Can't say I've ever specifically done a Roslyn Extension. But when I've needed a separate class lib in a VSIX, I've just added a new class library project to the VSIX solution and referenced it like normal.

Comment: @HiredMind hmm okay that seems simple. I was trying to do that before but I kept getting runtime mismatches. But if it works that simply then great thanks I'll try it out tomorrow

Comment: @HiredMind How Do you Reference an Assembly from Portable Library?  VsStudio Says it can only reference portable libraries

Comment: You would have to reference your portable code from your non-portable code. You could also use dependency injection to load non-portable code from portable code (I prefer Ninject but there are many others).

Comment: Turns out the vsix by default is portable I just switched it to be regular .net and it still works